# queryParamMap observable fires unexpectedly when params has an array and also using named router outlets

Tags: angular, observable, query-string

In a component I'm listening to `ActivatedRoute.queryParamMap` for changes. When I navigate by using the router and specify `queryParamsHandling: 'preserve'`, I expect the queryParamMap observable not to fire. It works except for when there's an array of parameters, e.g. **?a=1&a=2&a=3**. In my example I'm using named router outlets, and I haven't seen it happening when not using them. Have I set up routing  incorrectly?

If you look at [this stackblitz](https://angular-routing-navigation-example-91zrfd.stackblitz.io) (source [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routing-navigation-example-91zrfd)) with the dev console open you'll see the observable firing when you click **Navigate**. If you change the query string to something simple, e.g. **?a=1** then it only fires the first time.